# Avoid multiple coding by looping once

Tags: c#

I have this code here which i use to draw controls and i use a foreach to go through every element.

```
foreach (e.Control ctrl in Sheet1.Controls)
{
    switch (ctrl.TYPE)
    {
       case "StaticText":
            CompareControls.StaticText lbl = new CompareControls.StaticText();
            page1.tabPage1.Controls.Add(lbl);
               break;
       case "CheckBox":
               break;
     }
}
```

I need to do exactly the same for Sheet2.Controls, how do i avoid the copy paste?

Comment: Create a method that takes in a Sheet as a parameter

Comment: could you please elaborate? i'm not good with methods

Comment: What is the type of Sheet1, Sheet2. Pass that type in a method as parameter and loop through it.

Comment: `public void AddControls(Sheet sheet)` (Also, note if you really want to get clever you can remove the switch with `Activator.CreateInstance(ctrl.GetType());`)..

Comment: it's a property, how do i write it please?

Comment: If you not good with methods, you should read a book for basic beginer programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method which takes the control-collection as parameter. Something like:

```
private void Function(IEnumerable<Control> controls)
        {
            foreach (e.Control ctrl in controls)
            {
                switch (ctrl.TYPE)
                {
                    case "StaticText":
                        CompareControls.StaticText lbl = new CompareControls.StaticText();
                        page1.tabPage1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                        break;
                    case "CheckBox":

                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then you can call it:

```
Function(Sheet1.Controls);
```

Comment: so my variable is expressed somewhere like this:Sheet1.Controls, what kind of variable is it?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract it into a separate method (maybe static)

```
public static void MethodName (IEnumerable<Control> controls)
{
    foreach (var ctrl in controls)
    {
        switch (ctrl.TYPE)
        {
           case "StaticText":
              CompareControls.StaticText lbl = new CompareControls.StaticText();        
              page1.tabPage1.Controls.Add(lbl);        
              break;

           case "CheckBox":        
              break;        
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of Sheet1, Sheet2. say - Sheet.

```
private void loopThroughSheet(Sheet _sheet)
{
   foreach (e.Control ctrl in _sheet.Controls)
            {
                switch (ctrl.TYPE)
                {
                    case "StaticText":
                        CompareControls.StaticText lbl = new CompareControls.StaticText();


                        page1.tabPage1.Controls.Add(lbl);

                        break;

                    case "CheckBox":

                        break;

                }
            }
}
```

now in you main code just call `loopThroughSheet(Sheet1)` and `loopThroughSheet(Sheet2)`

Comment: how do i add another integer in the method, i need to parse and integer

Comment: This is how the sheet itself is accessed: public e.Sheet Sheet1 { get; set; }, how do i parse it in the loopThroughSheet method? as what type?

Answer (score 0):

use the overload in this way

```
foreach (e.Control ctrl in Sheet1.Controls)
{   
    DoOperation(ctrl)
}
```

then outside

```
public void function DoOperation(CompareControls.StaticText ctrl){
  CompareControls.StaticText lbl = new CompareControls.StaticText();
  page1.tabPage1.Controls.Add(lbl);
}

public void function DoOperation(CheckBox ctrl){

}
```

in this way you can manage every type of Controls without adding a `case` in the `switch`. You need only to add an overload of `DoOperation` function

Comment: Please this is the way i express the sheet1 public e.Sheet Sheet1 { get; set; }, what type is it?

Comment: @AniAni I suppose Sheet type